# When is it okay to combine answers to form a superanswer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, specific-answer

I just had a flag rejected by moderator for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r/40554139#40554139).  The answer is quite clearly the combination of 2 other answers, perhaps an attempt at an even better answer.  Even though it is community wiki and reputation will not be earned for it, it seems to open the door for great abuse if posters can do this in general.

So why in this case was it okay to combine answers and what is the general guidance for doing so?

Comment: I declined that flag, because I saw no reason to delete that answer. The answer itself doesn't copy the wording or code of those other answers, it combines the concepts of the answers to create something new. The answerer even went so far as to provide acknowledgement of the source answers. I don't see any problem with that, nor any abuse this might lead to.

Comment: @BradLarson After reading the duplicate link, I see that the rationale is given on that page.  I do not agree with it, but I see why it would be declined now.